# IFERROR and IF Formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put `=IFERROR(IF(C$1>-1,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),""),0)` in defined range G1:H10

```
Me.Range("G1:H10").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(C$1>-1,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),""),0)"
```

The code doesn't work and I think it's because of `IF` and `IFERROR`
Any help how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Me.Range("G1:H10").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(C$1>-1,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),""""),0)"

Comment: Oh.. it's because of quotes...